# Non-Repeating Error Handling in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling, yii

In my college days I remember a php code that handles errors like this..

```
$rs = $mymodel->find("usr=:usr",array("usr"=>"mahan")) on error echo $mymodel->geterror();
```

but i know the code above is wrong...

It's an error handling code I could not remember anymore..

maybe you would suggest something like this

```
/**First code suggestion**/
    if(!mymodel->find("usr=:usr",array("usr"=>"mahan"))){
        $rs = mymodel->find("usr=:usr",array(":usr"=>"mahan"));
    }
```

or like this

```
/**Second code suggestion**/
    try{
       $rs = mymodel->find("usr=:usr",array("usr"=>"mahan"));
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
      dump($e);
    }
```

My problem is **I don't want to repeat the same operation** just to test it if it will have errors(shown on the first code suggestion).

And the second code suggestion doesn't work.

the error handling I shown on very foremost of my question is wrong but I think it would solve my problem(I just don't remember the right one)... if not tell me your suggestions.

I'm using Yii Framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't understand where you hit the road block because you can still assign to a variable:

```
if (! $rs = $mymodel->find("usr=:usr",array("usr"=>"mahan")))
{
   # failed.
}
```

So there is no need to execute the same function again.

Comment: Yes you can do that. It's explained in the manual on the [*Expressions* page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.expressions.php).

Answer (score 1):

You're probably thinking about the infamous `mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error( ) );` construct. PHP has never had a "on error doSomething" structure. That said, the above structure can still be used:

```
<?php

function foo( ) {
    return false;
}

function error( $string ) {
    echo $string;
}

$rs = foo( ) or error( 'Alas' );
```

If `foo( )` returns `false`, that would mean `error( 'Alas' );` is called. If `foo( )` returns anything that can evaluate to true (such as true, an int > 1, a non-empty string, a resource or a resultset), the `error( 'Alas' )` will never be called.

Personally, though, I like the following construct better:

```
<?php

function foo( ) {
    return false;
}

function error( $string ) {
    echo $string;
}

$rs = foo( );

if( $rs === false ) { 
    error( 'Alas' );
}
```

If a user can not be found, I don't see this as an "exceptional" situation, just that the user isn't found. Exceptions are extremely useful, but I tend to use them for the bubbling qualities in situations where I can't handle the request any further.

Comment: thank you for letting me remember this thing ^^ anyways how can it be infamous? anyways don't mind me thanks ^^

Comment: @Mahan Because or die( mysql_error( ) ) always displayed the error to the user. That's not very polite, nor secure ;) That's why it has such a bad reputation.